# A weird behavior with push notification

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification

Ok, so I override `getNotification()` method in my custom receiver in order to prevent from a push notification to be shown when the app is in foreground.

```
@Override
protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Notification n = super.getNotification(context, intent);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification_id = intent.getExtras().getInt("NOTIFICATION_TYPE");

    if(ParseUtils.isAppOpened == null || !ParseUtils.isAppOpened) {
        Log.d("getNotification", "Im here");
        mNotificationManager.notify(notification_id, n);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The only problem is that whenever i send more then one push notification to a phone, only the last notification that has been sent is shown on the notification bar, and that's a behavior i would like to change.

Another thing, how can i "merge" all the notification to one notification? Like in whatsapp when you get more than one notification they all appears together in one box of notification...

Edit:

if im doing something like this:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject("{\"alert\": \"A message\",
                               \"NOTIFICATION_TYPE\": \"random number\",);
```

and then:

```
push.setData(data);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```

that should be good?

EDIT 2:

```
data = new JSONObject("{\"alert\": \"Hey pal\"+\", it looks like \"+cur_user.get(realName)+\" added you to the list '\"+list_name+\"'. press on me to check it.\",\"NOTIFICATION_TYPE\": \"listId\"}");
```

it says NOTIFICATION_TYPE is zero...
listId is a var of unique number. Is this the right way to add variables to JSONobject?

Answer (score 1):

I can try to answer the first part :

```
notification_id = intent.getExtras().getInt("NOTIFICATION_TYPE");
```

`notification_id` determines if a new notification will replace an existing notification or come in addition to it. If you send two messages with the same value of "NOTIFICATION_TYPE", the second notification will replace the first.

Comment: than how can i send a different NOTIFICATION_TYPE?

Comment: @kitsuneFox That's something you send from your server, so you should have control of what value you send for the "NOTIFICATION_TYPE" key.

Comment: @kitsuneFox Yes, if you're sending a random NOTIFICATION_TYPE, you'll see all the messages in the notifications bar (assuming all those random numbers are unique)

Comment: ok, fixed it. but now if i add for example data.put("NOTIFICATION_TYPE",1); i still get that the value is 0 instead of 1

Comment: ok i used UUID.randomUUID().hashCode() to generate  unique number..thanks anyway